# I want to change using C# the style of a set of shapefiles once I have uploaded them or while I am uploading them

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, c#, rest, style

I am using C# and the WebRequest class to create a worksapce and then another WebRequest to create a datastore and upload a folder full of shapefiles to a geoserver. However, I would also like to change the style of the uploaded shapefiles to another style that has already been installed on the geoserver. Any ideas?

Lazaros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did....

Assumptions: I have a `List<string>` named `layers` that contains my layer names, I have a string called `style` that contains the style name, I have a class `SessionConfig` defined as follows and being populated with appropriate values (url, username, password etc):

```
static class SessionConfig
{
    public static string url = null;
    public static string username = null;
    public static string password = null;
    // public static string locationOfCurl = null;
    public static string workspaceName = null;
    public static string storeName = null;
    public static string locationOfShapeFiles = null;
};
```

Then the code to change the style of each layer in my workspace/datastore is as follows:

```
    string responseFromServer = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < layers.Count; i++)
            {
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SessionConfig.url + "/rest/layers/" +
                                               SessionConfig.workspaceName + ":" + layers[i]);
                    request.ContentType = "text/xml";
                    request.Method = "PUT";
                    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SessionConfig.username, SessionConfig.password);

                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("<layer><defaultStyle><name>"+style+"</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>");
                    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();
                    WebResponse response = null;

                    bool done = false;

                    try
                    {
                        while (!done)
                        {
                            response = request.GetResponse();
                            response.Close();
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is 100% good code but it works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: By the vote count and up/down vote button, there is a greyed out check Mark. Check it to make it green. That marks it as answered.